# How do I pass variables to a function after the object is instantiated?

Tags: javascript

It's easy to pass variables to a new object at the time it is instantiated.  For example the code below works perfect.

```js
var CreatureStory, zombie;
 
function CreatureStory(species, action) {
  this.species = species;
  this.action = action;
  this.story = function() {
  console.log('The ' +this.species +' is about to ' +this.action +'.');
  }
}
 
zombie = new CreatureStory('zombie', 'walk');  //variables passed in here.
 
zombie.story();  // But how would I pass them in here?
```

But, what if I needed to pass them into the object after it was created?  For example, the code below doesn't get the variables into the already created object.  Their values show as `undefined`.

```
zombie.story('zombie', 'walk');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function doesn't accept any parameters you can't add parameters to it.
You either change the funtion to accept parameters; or change the object attributes before calling `story`

Like:

```js
var CreatureStory, zombie;
 
function CreatureStory(species, action) {
  this.species = species;
  this.action = action;
  this.story = function() {
  console.log('The ' +this.species +' is about to ' +this.action +'.');
  }
}
 
zombie = new CreatureStory('zombie', 'walk');
zombie.action = 'run';
zombie.story();  // the zombie now will run
```

Comment: `zombie.action = 'run';`  Interesting, that's how you do it after the fact.  The variables aren't passed in inside of `( )` but the values are set with an `=`.  Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass parameters to `story` method.

```js
var CreatureStory, zombie;
 
function CreatureStory(species, action) {
  this.species = species;
  this.action = action;
  this.story = function(species, action) { // Like this !!!!
     this.species = species;
     this.action = action;
     console.log('The ' +this.species +' is about to ' +this.action +'.');
  }
}
 
zombie = new CreatureStory('zombie', 'walk');  //variables passed in here.
 
zombie.story('monster', 'sleep');  // But how would I pass them in here?
```

Furthermore, I update `species` and `action` properties to reflect the new values

Answer (score 1):

After its created, you can assign values to the object like this: 
zombie.action="sit"

Thien zombie.story() will return "This zombie is about to sit"

Answer (score 1):

change `this.species` and `this.action` to `var species`  and `var action`

```js
var CreatureStory, zombie;
 
function CreatureStory(species, action) {
  var species = species;
  var action = action;
  this.story = function() {
  console.log('The ' +species +' is about to ' +action +'.');
  }
}
 
zombie =  new CreatureStory('zombie', 'walk');  //variables passed in here.
 
zombie.story();  // But how would I pass them in here?
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you update your this.story function as given below:

```
var CreatureStory, zombie;

function CreatureStory(species, action) {
  this.species = species;
  this.action = action;
  this.story = function(species, action) {
    species = species || this.species;
    action = action || this.action;
    console.log('The ' + species +' is about to ' + action +'.');
  }
}

zombie = new CreatureStory('zombie', 'walk');  //variables passed in here.

zombie.story();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and understand prototypical inheritance in JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

> It is essential to understand the prototypal inheritance model before
>   writing complex code that makes use of it. Also, be aware of the
>   length of the prototype chains in your code and break them up if
>   necessary to avoid possible performance problems. Further, the native
>   prototypes should never be extended unless it is for the sake of
>   compatibility with newer JavaScript features.

Answer (score 0):

```
var CreatureStory, zombie;

function CreatureStory(species, action) {
  this.species = species;
  this.action = action;
  this.story = function(speciesNew, actionNew) {
  this.species=speciesNew;
  this.action=actionNew
  console.log('The ' +this.species +' is about to ' +this.action +'.');
  }
}

zombie = new CreatureStory('zombie', 'walk');  //variables passed in here.

zombie.story('zombieNew', 'walkNew');  // But how would I pass them in here?
```